# Почему диапазон A-z включает в себя дополнительные символы, кроме букв?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

`/^[\-\.\s\'A-яA-zЁёәіңғүұқөһӘІҢҒҮҰҚӨҺ]*$/` - это регулярное выражение почему-то пропускает `^\_`. Как правильно написать, чтобы оно не пропускало эти символы?

Comment: как минимум, точку уберите из списка

Comment: @splash58 А точка вам чем не угодила, внутри списка она означает именно саму себя

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/wS6wQ1/1 Ничего не пропускает. В чем проблема-то?

Comment: @Mike, со слешами это какой-то баг. В истории видно что это я их добавил, хотя не помню чтобы я их добавлял.

Comment: @Mike, проверил, они были в исходном сообщении, но без вставки текста как кода парсер их съедает. Когда пользователь `@koks_rs` правил сообщение, он разметил регулярное выражение как код и все отобразилось как надо. Ничего добавлено не было.

Comment: @Mike во! а я ее экранирую всё время :)

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> A-яA-z
> ```

```
А-Яа-яA-Za-z
```

Про `Ёё` не забыл - она есть дальше в оригинальном выражении.

PS: Сколько ж можно...

Comment: Коллега, а Вам не кажется что в последнее время вопросы по `JS` и подобным вещам (типа регулярок) на удивление туп... лёгкие? Как если бы кто-то даже не подумал глянуть в учебник/ману.

Comment: @Other, не знаю, мне половину даже читать лень...Вроде вчера был хороший вопрос про apply. Хотя тоже несложный.

Comment: `А-ЯЁа-яёA-Za-z` букву **ё** забыли. [ссылка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#cite_note-5) PS: Сколько ж можно...

Comment: @АлександрАндреев, не забыл. Она в оригинальном выражении дальше прописана - вместе с остальными специфическими буквами.

Comment: Да, таких бы вопросов [тот, который про `apply`, занятные штуки позволяет делать], да побольше. Просто оповещения показывают все вопросы по меткам, а там даже читать страшно. Никак не пойму с чем это связано - неужели `JS` у нас так не в ходу, что внимательное чтение `learn.javascript.ru` могло бы убрать 80% вопросов по теме. То же и к регуляркам.

Comment: @Other, вопросы не тупые. В явном виде это не гуглится. Если вы дадите ссылку на мануал по этому случаю - честь вам и хвала.

Comment: @Qwertiy, было бы неплохо указать в своем ответе, почему так происходит, а не просто исправить ошибку

Comment: @VenZell, в этом загвоздка - ссылки на ману давать вроде как нельзя, а просто скопировать оттуда - можно. И дать гугл-ответ тоже нельзя, хотя первая ссылка может содержать объёмную и подробную статью о решении. С блекджеком и пояснениями. Но ведь народу лень! Накипело. И вот пример: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/522701/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-js

Comment: @Other, в качестве ответа - нет. Нужна хотя бы краткая выдержка из основной части. Как комментарий - можно же. Посылы в гугл - да, запрещены.

Comment: @VenZell, а смысл копировать с одного места на второе? Не на одном сайте, так на втором будет. И тот же MDN вполне может существовать побольше SO, маны целее будут.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, к ТС особо претензий нет (разве что `A-z` "повеселила"), ссылку удалить не могу - время правки вышло, да и зачем? Как пример - хороша, на большее и не ставилась. Что мета сделает? На смену одному не любителю чтения правил/учебников придёт второй, который даже не узнает как покарали прошлого страшными минусами, которые, к слову, для них явно ничего не значат. И SO не первые, кто заражён спорами "дай, сделай".

Comment: @Other, насчёт копирования полагаю, что это перегиб в развитии сообщества. Среди активных участников сообщества явно преобладают готовые писать длинные развёрнутые ответы. С одной стороны это обеспечивает высокое качество ответов, — с другой, ограничивает приток участников, готовых давать правильные ответы, но которым неохота писать «простыни». И поставить ссылку на статью с верным решением легче, чем переписывать статью. Да, внешние ссылки вымирают, но я ведь [*предложил решение*](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2988/199934), люто заминусованное.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, ответы-ссылки - довольно сомнительные ответы (хотя я был бы доволен, гуглу же позволяем это делать). Но отвечать на почти одинаковые вопросы, на столь же **не** глубокую тему, каждый раз расписывая что-где-когда... Хотел было предложить создать help-pages на каждый язык/метку с описанием основных проблем, но, здраво подумав, стало ясно - если правила не каждый читает, то страницы и подавно. Вот и крутимся меж проблемой и отсутствия нормального решения (против глупости ищут пилюльку уже сколько веков?).

Comment: @Other, > Как пример - хороша. — Не думаю. Представьте, если бы в комментарии к Вашему вопросу, плохому, по мнению других участников, в комментарии бы привели другой, ещё более худший вопрос, который к Вашему не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: Вот вы тут смеётесь, что вопросы глупые, а даже у меня решето оказывается, ибо много где в интернетах пишут `A-zА-я`, а про то, что оно берёт диапазоны по ASCII (точнее на самом деле по юникоду вроде) никто нигде не отмечает, а сам никогда просто не задумывался

Comment: @СашаЧерных, Тогда это проблема уже ответа-ссылки. Есть хорошие, а есть плохие. Чтобы не разбираться каждый раз что и как можно, запретили все. Как в РФ: мы не можем разобраться кто смотрит сайт с, допустим, +18, поэтому запретим всем смотреть. Приходится прокси/зеркала юзать (http://lurkmirror.ml/).

Comment: @andreymal, этот вопрос вообще надо было как дубликат закрыть. Но мне проще написать эту строчку с исправлением, чем искать охапку таких же вопросов. Они тут рядом точно есть, причём не один. Кстати, я бы вообще флаг `i` поставил и написал только один регистр, если это возможно.

Answer (score 1):

#### Обновлено с уточнениями по кодировкам

Рассмотрим таблицу ASCII символов (взята [отсюда](http://vbbook.ru/ascii-tablica-simvolov/)):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`-` работает как указатель на диапазон символов.

Рассмотрим, что включает в себя диапазон символов `A-z` согласно таблице.
Этот диапазон включает в себя символы с 65 по 122, среди которых помимо букв латинского алфавита в разном регистре присутствуют `\`, `^` и `_`.  Как раз те символы, которые вы не планировали включать в выражение, но, по неосторожности, включили.

С русскими символами тоже все не так просто. В Unicode почти все буквы русского алфавита в верхнем и нижнем регистре (кроме `ё` и `Ё`) укладываются в диапазон `0410 - 044F`. У `Ё` код `0401`, а у `ё` код `0451`.
Поэтому приходится формировать такой диапазон для букв русского алфавита:  `[а-яА-ЯЁё]`. Здесь вы все сделали правильно.

---

Для справки: в javascript можно пользоваться и альтернативным синтаксисом диапазона для русских букв: `[\u0410-\u044f\u0401\u0451]`, что полностью эквивалентно `[а-яА-ЯЁё]`.

---

Вывод здесь один: надо осторожнее пользоваться диапазонами.

В вашем случае необходимо вместо `A-яA-z` использовать `а-яА-Яa-zA-Z`. Полный пример:

```
/^[\-\.\s\'а-яА-Яa-zA-ZЁёәіңғүұқөһӘІҢҒҮҰҚӨҺ]*$/
```

Comment: Эм.. Под эту досовскую таблицу ответ не подходит. Для неё должно быть не `А-Яа-яЁё`, а `А-Яа-пр-яЁё` или даже `А-пр-ё` (вот уж помучается тот, кто такое выражение увидит). Но этой кодировкой уже не пользуются. По крайней мере, точно не на js.

Comment: вы ошиблись, не 44-101, а 65-122

Comment: @Qwertiy, я бы невнимателен, когда искал картинку с ASCII таблицей. Обновил на актуальную.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, вы правы, не в ту колонку смотрел. Обновил ответ.

Comment: ASCII содержит только символы с 0 по 127 и ни на символ больше, со 128 по 255 это в данном случае уже Windows-1251