# Регулярное выражение для строки, состоящей только из кириллицы, латиницы и пробелов

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужна проверка на присутствие в строке символов. Строка должна содержать только символы кириллицы, латиницы, пробелы и ничего кроме. Пробовал как в js регулярку составить, но почему-то работает совсем неправильно!

```
 if (preg_match("/[^A-zА-я]/","daksks sdsd ывыв1234234") == 0) {
 echo "Да";
 }
```

Comment: Уже был подобный вопрос.
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/522698/13336 - Здесь объясняется, почему регулярное выражение работает не так, как вы ожидаете

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
preg_match( "/[^a-zа-яё ]/iu", $text );
```

Только кириллица, латиница и пробел.

Comment: По-моему пробела не хватает в квадратных скобках?

Comment: Да, спасибо, упустил

Comment: @ReinRaus а заглавные буквы он тоже будет считать допустимыми???

Comment: @dantelol, для этого и существует флаг `\i`.

Comment: @ReinRaus так получается? /[^`a-zа-яё ]/iu

Answer (score 5):

Вы можете воспользоваться следующим вариантом

```
<?php
if (!preg_match("/[^\w\d\s]/u", "daksks sdsd ывыв1234234")) {
  echo "Да";
}
```

Модификатор u используется для UTF8-текста. Если для вас классы \w, \d и \s слишком общие, можно воспользоваться таким выражением

```
<?php
if (!preg_match("/[^0-9a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ ]/u", "daksks sdsd ывыв1234234")) {
  echo "Да";
}
```

Выше перечисленные выражения учитывают цифры, если их нужно исключить, то выражение следует поправить `"/[^\w\s]/u"` и `"/[^a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ ]/u"`, соответственно.

Comment: Пропустит цифры, переносы строк, знаки горизонтальной и вертикальной табуляции.

Comment: Спасибо, добавил замечание.