# Обратный слэш в результате совпадения по регулярному выражению

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Вопрос: почему при использовании регулярного выражения: `|[A-z]+|` к строке `'Illuminate\Routing'`, в выдачу попадает эта же строка, не смотря на то, что в ней обратный слэш.

Код:

```
preg_match_all('|[A-z]+|', 'Illuminate\Routing', $match);
```

Результат:

```html
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Illuminate\Routing
        )

)
```

Экранирование слэша в строке не помогает.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему диапазон A-z включает в себя дополнительные символы, кроме букв?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/522682/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bd-a-z-%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b1%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что этот символ входит в этот интервал. [Смотри таблицу ASCII](http://mojainformatika.ru/images/stories/pascal/nachalo/kodovaya%20tablica%20ASCII..png).

A-имеет код 65, z - 122, \ - 92, т.е. между ними находится.

Правильней A-Za-z