# Регулярное выражение для латинских и русских букв для UTF-8

Tags: регулярные-выражения, utf-8, cp866

Если касается кодировки `cp866`, то мы можем посмотреть таблицу символов, посмотреть следование символов этих символов в таблице, и составить простую регулярку, перебирая непрерывные диапазоны:

```
[A-Za-zА-пр-ё]+
```

Для `UTF-8` ничего другого не приходит в голову как:

```
[A-Za-zАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя]+
```

**А можно ли как-то компактнее для `UTF-8`?**

Comment: Ничего не понял, но очень интересно.

Comment: Какой язык программирования? И что за регулярки - где вы их вводить собрались?

Comment: У UTF-8 символы русского языка также идут подряд, что можно написать А-Я, а-я - поэтому вопрос непонятен

Comment: @SlimRG в данном случае я пытаюсь использовать в `JavaScript`. Хотя вы правы - нужно смотреть `UTF-8` таблицу также. Ступил я)

Comment: А почему бы вообще не использовать `/\p{L}/u` для поиска букв?

Comment: Спасибо за совет - интересное решение! Но неподходящее мне. Так как мне не нужно "буквы для всех языков", и не нужен `UTF-16`. А именно так "расшифровывает" эту регулярку https://regex101.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

См. [таблицу Юникода](https://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/) и составляйте необходимый вам *символьный класс* с выбранными диапазонами:

```
[A-Za-zА-яЁё]
```

Иногда при проблемах с кодировкой лучше использовать запись вида `\uXXXX`:

```
[A-Za-z\u0410-\u044F\u0401\u0451]
```

***Подробности***

**[Английские буквы](https://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0020-007F)**: `[A-Za-z]` (но не `[A-z]`! См. [Почему диапазон A-z включает в себя дополнительные символы, кроме букв?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/522682))

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**[Русские буквы](https://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0400-04FF)**: `[А-яЁё]`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очепятка у меня, я просто забыл маленькие `a-z`. Плюсую)

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо, **SlimRG**, действительно в `UTF-8`, если глянуть на диапазон - еще проще получается:

```
[A-Za-zА-яЁё]+
```