# Как разрешить только один пробел в регулярном выражении?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите как правильно разрешить только один пробел в регулярном выражении?, по типу Вася Пупкин, и дальше уже пробелы нельзя, на этом примере

```
preg_match("#^([A-zА-я-ІіЇїЄє])+$#ui", $name))
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: `^([A-zА-я-ІіЇїЄє])+\s([A-zА-я-ІіЇїЄє])+$`

Comment: @DiMithras, похоже что и круглые скобки так же можно убрать...

Comment: @ksa да, вполне, они не нужны. Придерживался предоставленного примера. Так то по-хорошему через `\w` можно сделать.

Comment: @DiMithras `\w` включает в себя диапазон чисел и знак нижнего подчеркивания, что будет не совсем верно, так же как и `\s`  включает в себя горизонтальные и вертикальные пробельные символы

Comment: @ipatev_nn и цифры включает, тут конечно, от изначального запроса зависит, но вопрос про пробел был

Answer (score 3):

Сначала следует обратить внимание на `[A-z]`  в вашем выражении: этот щаблон [находит не только латинские буквы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1198188/182013), вместо него надо использовать `[A-Za-z]`. Знак `-` лучше поставить в конце символьного класса, а не сразу после диапазона символов.

Чтобы разрешить (но не требовать) один пробел в вашем регулярном выражении, используйте

```php
preg_match("#^[A-Za-zА-яІіЇїЄє-]+(?: [A-Za-zА-яІіЇїЄє-]+)?$#Du", $name)
```

Вместо обычного пробела можно использовать `\s`, который разрешит использование любых пробельных символов (`\h` для всех пробельных символов, кроме символов перевода строки).

Варианты:

```
"#^\p{L}+(?: \p{L}+)?$#Du"
"#^\p{L}+(?: \p{L}+)?\z#u"
"#^\p{L}+(?:\h\p{L}+)?\z#u"
"#^(?:\p{L}\p{M}*+)+(?:\h(?:\p{L}\p{M}*+)+)?\z#u"
```

`\p{L}` находит любую букву.

`\z` означает абсолютный конец строки (в отличие от `$`, для которого требуется флаг `D`).

Последний пример поддерживает также диакритические знаки.