# Регулярное выражение для поиска не русских букв

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть файл примерно с таким содержимым:

```
"8";"Курск";"Россия"
"9";"Lipetsk";"Lipetsk Oblast, Russia"
"10";"Арол";"Арлоўская вобласць, Расія"
"11";"Ryazan";"Ryazan Oblast, Russia"
"12";"Smolensk";"Smolensk Oblast, Russia"
"13";"Tambov";"Tambov Oblast, Russia"
"14";"Цвер";"Цвярская вобласць, Расія"
"28";Махачкала;"Республика Дагестан, Россия"
```

Мне надо из него получить всё, что не на русском языке *(просто проверяю есть ли не русские буквы. Если знаете более оптимальное решение, что-то вроде переводчика, буду благодарен)*. Делаю следующим образом:

```
$handle = fopen(__DIR__."/regions.csv", "r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, '', ';')) !== FALSE) {
    if(preg_match("/[^а-я ]+/msiu", mb_convert_encoding($data[2], "UTF-8"))){
      $notRus[] = array(mb_convert_encoding($data[0], "UTF-8"), mb_convert_encoding($data[1], "UTF-8"), mb_convert_encoding($data[2], "UTF-8"));
    }
}
fclose($handle);
// Output
$handle = fopen(__DIR__."/notRus.csv", "w");
foreach ($notRus as $notRu)
{
   fputcsv($handle, $notRu, ";", '"');
   $counter++;
}
echo $counter;
fclose($handle);
```

На выходе получаю следующее: (Курск убрался, а Махачкала нет).

```
9;Lipetsk;"Lipetsk Oblast, Russia"
10;Арол;"Арлоўская вобласць, Расія"
11;Ryazan;"Ryazan Oblast, Russia"
12;Smolensk;"Smolensk Oblast, Russia"
13;Tambov;"Tambov Oblast, Russia"
14;Цвер;"Цвярская вобласць, Расія"
28;Махачкала;"Республика Дагестан, Россия"
```

Это из-за пробела? Но в `preg_match` стоит же пробел: `"/[^а-я ]+/msiu"`

Comment: Ваша регулярка ищет вообще совершенно не то что вы описали :) любой символ или количество символов не из списка :) в частности ```[^а-я ]+``` это всё что угодно кроме русской буквы, т.е. запятая в любой из строк подходит под вашу регулярку :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков ну, как-то так и получилось там же всякие у с чёрточкой есть. Большая часть выбирается нормально. Почему только с Махачкалой и ей подобными проблема такая?

Comment: В регулярке проблема или в том как вы ее используете, пока не понятно что именно нужно, 1) все строки в которых вообще нет русских букв 2) если есть одна хоть одна иностранная буква.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков второй вариант, хоть одна иностранная. Там же ещё города через дефис некоторые пишутся, потому так делал, но не получилось

Comment: ```if(preg_match('/[A-z]+/',$str)) {echo "Есть иностранная буква";}```

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков [А вот и нет](https://3v4l.org/NqrSL).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew
Забавно, чтот я давно не заглядывал в кодовую таблицу походу, или чего то не понимаю :) Второй вариант исключает первую багу, хоть я и не понимаю пока что почему она появляется xD ```if(preg_match('/[A-Za-z]+/',$str)) {echo "Есть иностранная буква";}```

з.ы. заглянул в таблицу кодовую, и правда 6 лишних символов собирал :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков См. [Почему диапазон A-z включает в себя дополнительные символы, кроме букв?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/522682/182013)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Почему он включает лишние символы я догадался сразу :) но почему то пропуск в 6 символов ускользнул из памяти, до вашего прошлого комментария я считал что после ```Z``` идет ```a``` :) уже глянул таблицу аски символов и увидел на что еще он реагировал :) спасибо за подсказку :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Я проверил ваши примеры, однако `Арлоўская` входит в условие `без иностранных букв`. В вопросе она не входила по причине того, что за ней шла `Расія`. Так как же переписать выражение, чтобы были `только русские` или если `есть хоть 1 не русская буква`?